# Elegant control flow in C++ (or any other language)

Tags: c++

I am writing a function which has many return points (depending on what conditions are true) and it does a bunch of `new`s at different points. At every return point, the set of `delete`s I need to do are different. And even then, I don't want to do them at different places. What is a good way to handle this?

Some details: Let us consider a function:

```
int MainClass::testFunction() {
  numThreads++;
  char *a = new char[100];
  // Some computation with a
  if (condition1) {
    numThreads--;
    return -1;
  } 
  char *b = new char[100];
  // Some computation with b
  if (condition2) {
    numThreads--;
    return 42;
  } 
  // Some more stuff. 
  numThreads--;
}
```

Now, before `return -1`, I need to do `delete a` while before `return 42`, I need to do `delete a; delete b;`. And you can imagine how this could get complicated if I had multiple return points.

Here are my solutions:

First solution: Put all deletes at the end of the function, put some labels, store the return value at return points, and use `goto` (yes, that dirty word!) to jump to appropriate deletes and return after executing those deletes.

In the above example, I could say

```
superset:
  delete b;
subset:
  delete a;
numThreads--;
```

And put `goto superset` before `return 42` and `goto subset` before `return -1`.

I don't like the solution for obvious reasons! :-)

Second solution: I can build an inner class instance, and do `new` on variables of that class instance. Like this...

```
int MainClass::testFunction() {
  class Local {
    char *a, *b;
    Local () : a(NULL), b(NULL) {}
    ~Local () { if (a != NULL) delete a; if (b != NULL) delete b; }
  };
  Local l = Local();
  l.a = new char[100];
  // Some computation with a
  if (condition1) {
    return -1;
  } 
  l.b = new char[100];
  // Some computation with b
  if (condition2) {
    return 42;
  } 
}
```

So, what is the problem? Well, how do I access `numThreads` variable that was in the method? I want to do `numThreads++` in the constructor for `Local` and `numThreads--` in the dtor of `Local`. If it helps, `testFunction` is also a member function of another class.

Thanks for reading.

**Update:** Allocating the array on stack is definitely one possibility, but I have run into stack overflow (ah... the name of this website :-)) doing large allocations on stack (stack size for threads is 2MB by default). What I wanted to address in this question was *general* resource acquisition and destruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um. You're WAY overcomplicating this. Just set `a` and `b` to NULL at the beginning. Surround the whole thing with a `try / catch`. If anything goes wrong, throw something (anything will do). In the `catch` block, call `delete` on all of the variables. `delete` will do nothing if the variable is NULL.

And if you need to do stuff with return variables, you could theoretically just `throw` the return value (yes, you can throw ints). Then when you're done cleaning up, just return the thrown value.

```
char *a = NULL, *b = NULL;

try
{
    a = ...;
    if(bad_thing)
        throw -1;

    b = ...;
    throw 42;
}
catch(int e)
{
    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    return e;
}
```

Comment: Looks promising. I will try this. By the way, `delete` on non-`new`ed memory gives errors. I tried that. :-)

Comment: Delete will only accept two things: something returned by `new`, or NULL. Anything else is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 9):

Read about [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)

Basically, never use `new` except in a constructor (or assignment), and never use `delete` except in a destructor.

Regarding your particular case, you can do the following:

(1) Just use `std::vector<char>`.
(2) Do `char a[100];` instead (this is stack allocated, an therefore is automatically collected).  This will only work if the `100` is a constant. You can also use `std::array<char, 100>` with a C++11 compiler (or `boost::array<char, 100>` if you have boost libraries installed).
(3) Use `alloca()` to allocate space on the stack (if `100` is not constant) (be careful with this).
(4) Write your own class which allocates memory using `new` in the constructor and deletes memory using `delete` in the destructor.

I would recommend (2) if `100` is a constant and not too big, otherwise (1).

Comment: Yeah, that is what I wanted to do... and this question was along those lines: how to do it.

Comment: @Yogi Sharma: `#include <vector>` `std::vector a(100);`

Comment: @Yogi `vector` has RAII built into it so for your purposes, you don't have to implement a class. You can just use `vector` like in SigTerm's answer.

Answer (score 4):

> What is a good way to handle this?

```
#include <vector>
int MainClass::testFunction() {
  numThreads++;
  std::vector<char> a(100);
  // Some computation with a
  if (condition1) {
    numThreads--;
    return -1;
  } 
  std::vector<char> b(100);
  // Some computation with b
  if (condition2) {
    numThreads--;
    return 42;
  } 
  // Some more stuff. 
  numThreads--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int MainClass::imp_testFunction() {

// perhaps break up a-compute, b-compute, some more stuff to
// separate methods if they are nontrivial.

// 100 chars should go on the stack (something like boost::array
// is ideal if you can use that), unless you know you are
// performing deep/recursive calls or have a small stack
// (e.g. embedded). for large or variable sized allocations,
// use something like a std::vector.
    char a[100];

// Some computation with a
    if (condition1) {
        return -1;
    }

    char b[100];
// Some computation with b
    if (condition2) {
        return 42;
    }
// Some more stuff.
}

int MainClass::testFunction() {
   // refactor this so you don't need to inc/dec at each exit.
    ++numThreads;
    const int ret(imp_testFunction());
    --numThreads;
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you MUST use this control flow with all this return, one solution could be to use smart pointers:

```
int MainClass::testFunction() {
  numThreads++;
  std::unique_ptr<char *> a(new char[100]);
  // Some computation with a
  if (condition1) {
    numThreads--;
    return -1;
  } 
  std::unique_ptr<char *> b(new char[100]);
  // Some computation with b
  if (condition2) {
    numThreads--;
    return 42;
  } 
  // Some more stuff. 
  numThreads--;
}
```

In the worst and weird case, maintaining your current control flow and NOT moving a or b they will be freed on exiting testFunction.